# emacs auto-complete plugin not showing drop down menu

Tags: emacs, autocomplete

I am an Emacs newbie. I am trying to install the auto-complete plugin using the Marmalade repository and was able to install it with the following warnings.

```
In ac-quick-help:
auto-complete.el:1281:19:Warning: called-interactively-p called with 0
arguments, but requires 1

In ac-mouse-1:
auto-complete.el:1517:20:Warning: reference to free variable `it'

In end of data:
auto-complete.el:1986:1:Warning: the following functions are not known to be defined:        popup-awhen,
popup-menu-item-of-mouse-event
```

But I am not able to access the drop down menu. When I try to do a `M-x autocomplete`, I get an error saying autocomplete not enabled.

I am using a Lubuntu 12.10 OS.

Comment: Try putting `(require 'auto-complete-config)
(ac-config-default)' in your .emacs file and restarting emacs.